# How insert a youtube video in python

Tags: python, video, youtube, ipython, display

I'm trying to insert a YouTube video in my code.

I have done this:

```
from IPython.display import YouTubeVideo
YouTubeVideo("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=inN8seMm7UI")
```

A picture of the video appears as a black box, shown below:

[image: Black box video]

I can't find a solution. Please help.

Comment: Im confused on what the use of this would be?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the ID of the Youtube video, not the full link:

```
from IPython.display import YouTubeVideo
YouTubeVideo("inN8seMm7UI")
```

Output:

[image: output and code]